# Using SQL Server Compact 4.0.0.1 with Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4, assemblies, sql-server-ce

#### Error:

`Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact.`

#### Inner Exception:

`{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"}`

#### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create new MVC3 Application
2. Add Nuget Package *EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact*

   `<package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="4.1.8482.2" />`
3. Create Model

   ```
   public class TaskItem
   {
       [Key]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Create DbContext

   ```
   public class TestContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<TaskItem> TaskItems { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. Home Controller

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var db = new TestContext();
       // breakpoint on Add() below
       db.TaskItems.Add(new TaskItem { Description = "Get shit done."});
       return View();
   }
   ```
6. Web.config Connection String and Runtime and System.Data

   `<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Test.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />`

   ```
   <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
         </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
     <system.data>
       <DbProviderFactories>
         <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
         <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
       </DbProviderFactories>
     </system.data>
   ```

### Question:

Web.config is all default... nothing funky here... all the DLLs are copy local and in bin... what am I missing? It's got to be something very simple.

---

#### Update:

Removing the Dependent Assembly section from web.config solved the problem, but I still need an explanation why in order to close the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the dependent assembly binding from your web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. 4.0.0.1 definitely existed but I kept on getting the same error as OP until I removed the binding redirect.

Comment: Kori, I deleted the same piece and it seems to have made the crash go away as well. I'd like to know why before I mark an answer, as this is vanilla out of the box installation. If you can find a definitive answer, I'll toss your the check. Meanwhile +1 for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code is created or not on your project

```
EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.cs under the App_Start folder

using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyStory.Tests.App_Start.EntityFramework_SqlServerCompact), "Start")]

namespace MyStory.Tests.App_Start {
    public static class EntityFramework_SqlServerCompact {
        public static void Start() {
            Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I cannot find out the dependentAssembly element for "System.Data.SqlServerCe" in my web.config, how about removing those and try again?